# Why does v-for work only for a split second?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got a weird problem that's happening to me in Vue.js. I don't know if it's my fault or a bug.

When I use v-for with a comma before it (v-bind), it doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't display anything. When I don't use a comma, I get this error `Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives`.

But if I add the comma back, it displays for a split second and then it gives me the aforementioned behavior.

Code in question:

```
<template>
  <div class="outside--wrapper">
      <form action="">
          <p :v-for="element in words1">{{ element }}</p>
      </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Crossword",
    data() {
        return {
            words1: {
                1: ["S","i","l","a"],
                2: ["S","i","l","a"],
                3: ["S","i","l","a"],
                4: ["S","i","l","a"],
            },
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it comma or colon? (, or :)

Comment: Sorry, English is not my main language. I meant colon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:v-for` is equivalent to `v-bind:v-for`
the error says list iteration should has a key (`v-bind:key` or `:key`)

the correct code is

```
<p v-for="(elements, key) in words1" :key="key">{{ elements }}</p>
```

see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Comment: Check his data, elements are also an array. you cannot print it to DOM.

Comment: This is correct, but instead of `{{ elements }}`, it's `{{ key }}`

Comment: array will be printed as JSON https://codepen.io/NateScarlet/pen/YzqWXoQ @sojin